# QML Acessar a galeria de imagens no iOS e Android

Tags: qt, galeria, qml

Estou desenvolvendo um app para `iOS` e `Android` e estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades para acessar a `galeria de images` dos dispositivos com QML.

Eu preciso listar as images da galeria de imagens em um `GridView`

Eu tenho tentado usar `QStandardPaths` mas só funciona para computadores dektop. Para smartphones rodando `iOS` and `Android` a pasta retornada é diferente da pasta da galeria de images..

Alguém sabe como fazer este acesso? Meu código está abaixo:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QtQml>

#include "caminhoimagens.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<caminhoImagens>("PathImagens", 1, 0, "CaminhoImagens");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

import PathImagens 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 360
    height: 640

    maximumHeight: 640
    minimumHeight: 640

    maximumWidth: 360
    minimumWidth: 360

    title: "Acessar Galeria Test"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        anchors.fill: parent

        ListModel {
            id: listModel
        }

        FolderListModel {
            id: folderListModel

            folder: "file://" + caminhoImagens.retornaCaminhoImagens()
            nameFilters: "*.jpeg"
        }

        CaminhoImagens {
            id: caminhoImagens
        }

        Item {
            id: listaFotosDelegate

            property Component delegateComponent: listaFotosDelegateComponent

            Component {
                id: listaFotosDelegateComponent

                Image {
                    id: imagem

                    source: folderListModel.folder + "/" + fileName

                    width: principal.width / 4.2
                    height: principal.width / 4.2

                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                }
            }
        }

        GridView {
            id: listaFotosGridView

            anchors.fill: parent

            clip: true

            model: folderListModel

            delegate: listaFotosDelegate.delegateComponent

            cellWidth: parent.width / 4
            cellHeight: parent.width / 4
        }
    }
}
```

caminhoimagens.h

```
#ifndef CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
#define CAMINHOIMAGENS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStandardPaths>

class caminhoImagens : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    QString retornaCaminhoImagens();

public:
    caminhoImagens();
};

#endif // CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
```

caminhoimagens.cpp

```
#include "caminhoimagens.h"

caminhoImagens::caminhoImagens()
{

}

QString caminhoImagens::retornaCaminhoImagens()
{
    return QStandardPaths::locate(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation, QString(), QStandardPaths::LocateDirectory);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo minha própria pergunta.

No iOS só crie um `FileDialog` no arquivo `QML` e defina `folder: shortcuts.pictures`. O `FileDialog` vai chamar a galeria do iOS.

No Android é um pouco mais difícil pois é preciso integrar com o Java

Eu fiz meu código usando `QAndroidJniObject` para escrever um código equivalente ao Java.

caminhoimagens.h

```
#ifndef CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
#define CAMINHOIMAGENS_H

#include <QObject>

#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

#include <QDebug>

class caminhoImagens : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString imagemCaminho READ imagemCaminho NOTIFY imagemCaminhoChanged)

public slots:
    void buscaImagem();
    void retornaImagem(QString path);

public:
    caminhoImagens();

    QString imagemCaminho();

private:
    QString m_imagemCaminho = "";

signals:
    void imagemCaminhoChanged();
};

#endif //CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
```

caminhoimagens.cpp

```
#include "caminhoimagens.h"

caminhoImagens::caminhoImagens()
{

}

void caminhoImagens::buscaImagem()
{
    imagePickerAndroid *imagePicker = new imagePickerAndroid();
    connect(imagePicker, SIGNAL(imagemCaminhoSignal(QString)), this, SLOT(retornaImagem(QString)));

    imagePicker->buscaImagem();
}

void caminhoImagens::retornaImagem(QString path)
{
    qDebug() << path;

    m_imagemCaminho = path;

    emit imagemCaminhoChanged();
}

QString caminhoImagens::imagemCaminho()
{
    return m_imagemCaminho;
}
```

imagepickerandroid.h

```
#ifndef IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
#define IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QtAndroidExtras>

#include <QDebug>

class imagePickerAndroid : public QObject, public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    imagePickerAndroid();

    void buscaImagem();

    virtual void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject & data);

signals:
    void imagemCaminhoSignal(QString);
};

#endif // IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
```

imagepickerandroid.cpp

```
#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

imagePickerAndroid::imagePickerAndroid()
{

}

void imagePickerAndroid::buscaImagem()
{
    QAndroidJniObject ACTION_PICK = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent");
    if (ACTION_PICK.isValid() && intent.isValid())
    {
        intent.callObjectMethod("setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", ACTION_PICK.object<jstring>());
        intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("image/*").object<jstring>());
        QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
        qDebug() << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
}

void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    qDebug() << "Trabalha com os dados";

    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        QString imagemCaminho = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;").callObjectMethod("getPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;").toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);

        qDebug() << imagemCaminho;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```